# General expression for a nonlinear recursive sequence and the sum of the terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations

A sequence is defined such that $$x_{r+1}= {x_r}^2-x_r, x_1= \frac{1}{3}$$

Can a general relation be found out in which all members can be expressed in terms of $x_1$?

Also an expression for $$\sum_{k=1}^n x_k$$ is to be derived. How can this be done?

I could not arrive at any assumption about the character of of $x_n$, like , for instance, that of linear recurrence sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a mostly positive [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map), in general the recurrence behaves chaotically (it's used in chaos theory) so a closed form solution is improbable. This [article](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ddns/2015/586783/) has much info with graphs and such on the logistic maps.

Comment: Can the first part of the question be done? That is, finding a general expression, if not the summation? By the way, thanks for INSPIRING me into the domain of modern math !

Comment: The first part doesn't have a solution, which implies that second also doesn't since $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}x_k-\sum_{k=1}^n x_k=x_{n+1}$